# Sphinx MVA for float values

Tags: sphinx

I have a table with has many tables:

```
company
id | name
---------
1  | a
2  | b
3  | c
```

```
company_address
id | company_id |         latitude |        longitude |
-------------------------------------------------------
1  |           1|0.9684982117632206|1.1395506188216191|
2  |           1|0.7874478257111129|0.6816976456543681|
3  |           2|0.9758854923552117| 0.744264348306201|
4  |           2|0.7860300249465478|0.6804121583003967|
5  |           2|0.7874478257111129|0.6816976456543681|
6  |           3|0.9684982117632206|1.1395506188216191|
```

`sql_attr_multi` do not support float type field, `sql_joined_field` was removed. How can I solve this problem? Maybe there are solutions besides GROUP_CONCAT()?

Comment: What's your goal?

Comment: @ManticoreSearch my goal is implement search companies through radius using by `GEODIST()` example `SELECT *, GEODIST(0.659298124, -2.136602399, latitude, longitude) as distance FROM companyIndex WHERE distance < 10000;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your easiest would be to arrange your sphinx 'documents' to be addresses, not strictly company. i.e., the unique document-id is the address table id. `company_address.id`

Keep the company-id as an attribute so can group IF really only want one result per company.

```
sql_query = SELECT a.*, c.name FROM company_address a INNER JOIN company c ON (c.id = company_id) 
sql_attr_uint = company_id
sql_attr_float = latitude
sql_attr_float = longitude
```

Then `GEODIST` will work on pretty much directly...

```
SELECT *, GEODIST(0.659298124, -2.136602399, latitude, longitude) AS distance 
   FROM addressIndex WHERE distance < 10000 GROUP BY company_id;
```

Or if you want each company address, don't include the `GROUP BY`.

The company name is still included as a field for full-text searches.

Comment: This solution is good for simple searching, but if you want search with FACET so faceted counts are wrong. I already wrote here [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59877911/how-to-group-mva-field-for-faceted-in-sphinx) Maybe I didn’t form the question correctly but I think the essence of the issue is clear.

Comment: Actually, I realized that in sphinx impossible to implement build index with multiple geo points where in as a result FACET return correctly counts.

Comment: Dont know exactly what your problem is but maybe can use `COUNT(DISTINCT company_id)` instead of `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Ah then found http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=16397 which replied to.